# Convert bootstrap3 DateTime picker to C# datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap Datetime picker v3 with following option

```
 $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            isRTL: Metronic.isRTL(),
            format: "dd MMyyyy hh:ii",
            pickerPosition: (Metronic.isRTL() ? "bottom-right" : "bottom-left")
        });
```

When I get the result of picker I get something like `"10 March 2016 - 10:50"` I can't convert it to C# datetime, c# return me following error

```
inputStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatetime.Text);
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParseExact()` will work very well with a custom format.  Here's an example:

```
string input = "10 March 2016 - 10:50";
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

I like to use the "Try" variants of parsing, to avoid exceptions.  If it fails, you get the default value (it's `MinValue` in the case of `DateTime`), no harm done.  You also get a `bool` value back, indicating the success or failure.  This example works, though.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses standard date and time format of your current culture settings *by default*. Looks like this format is not one of them.

In your case, you need to use custom format as `dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm`, *english-based* culture like `InvariantCulture` with `DateTime.ParseExact` method like;

```
var inputStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatetime.Text,
                                         "dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, another datetime format:

```
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            isRTL: Metronic.isRTL(),
            format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
            pickerPosition: (Metronic.isRTL() ? "bottom-right" : "bottom-left")
        });
```